# cant see ldap variables in windows apache 2.4

Tags: windows, apache-2.4, .htaccess, ldap, python

Working on a windows apache (2.4), I want to authenticate the users to a LDAP server

I have the following in the httpd.conf

```
<Directory "C:\Apache24\htdocs">
    LDAPReferrals Off
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthName "LDAP NAME"
    AuthType Basic
    AllowOverride None
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
</Directory>
```

and the following in the .htaccess file at the correct folder

```
AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=USER,CN=Users,DC=YY,DC=ZZZZZZZ,DC=QQQ"
AuthLDAPBindPassword "PASSWORD"
Require all denied
AuthLDAPUrl ldap://ldapIP:LDAPPORT/CN=XXX,DC=YY,DC=ZZZZZZZ,DC=QQQ?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)
Require valid-user
AuthLDAPRemoteUserAttribute sAMAccountName
AuthLDAPRemoteUserIsDN on
```

When I access the site, I get the user prompt and entering the right credentials does let me enter the site (entering the wrong ones will get a 401 - ok)

My issue is that I need to "check" who is the user that accessed the site, I understood that LDAP should insert the username that accessed the site under 'REMOTE_USER' in the environment variables - but checking 'set' on CMD, and checking `os.envrion` (on python - server side is written in python) shows nothing..

**EDIT:**

current httpd.conf file is:

```
<Directory "C:\Apache24\htdocs">
    LDAPReferrals Off
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthName "LDAP NAME"
    AuthType Basic
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
</Directory>
```

and current .htaccess file is:

```
AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=USER,CN=Users,DC=YY,DC=ZZZZZZZ,DC=QQQ"
AuthLDAPBindPassword "PASSWORD"
Require all denied
AuthLDAPUrl ldap://ldapIP:LDAPPORT/CN=XXX,DC=YY,DC=ZZZZZZZ,DC=QQQ?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)
Require valid-user
```

I've turned Apache debug logging, and seeing below is the relevant log - showing that he DOES 'ACCEPTING' my username.. but still can't "get" it from the environment variables..

```
Tue Jul 04 14:28:44.088576 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid PID1:tid TID1] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client IP:PORT1] AH01626: authorization result of Require all denied: denied
Tue Jul 04 14:28:44.089582 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid PID1:tid TID1] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client IP:PORT1] AH01626: authorization result of Require valid-user : granted
Tue Jul 04 14:28:44.089582 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid PID1:tid TID1] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client IP:PORT1] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
Tue Jul 04 14:28:44.558595 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid PID1:tid TID2] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client IP:PORT2] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: http://domain
Tue Jul 04 14:28:44.558595 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid PID1:tid TID2] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client IP:PORT2] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: http://domain
Tue Jul 04 14:28:44.559596 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid PID1:tid TID2] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client IP:PORT2] AH01626: authorization result of Require all denied: denied, referer: http://domain
Tue Jul 04 14:28:44.559596 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid PID1:tid TID2] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client IP:PORT2] AH01626: authorization result of Require valid-user : denied (no authenticated user yet), referer: http://domain
Tue Jul 04 14:28:44.559596 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid PID1:tid TID2] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client IP:PORT2] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied (no authenticated user yet), referer: http://domain
Tue Jul 04 14:28:44.559596 2017] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid PID1:tid TID2] mod_authnz_ldap.c(515): [client IP:PORT2] AH01691: auth_ldap authenticate: using URL ldap://ldapIP:LDAPPORT/CN=XXX,DC=YY,DC=ZZZZZZZ,DC=QQQ?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*), refrer: http://domain
Tue Jul 04 14:28:44.559596 2017] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid PID1:tid TID2] mod_authnz_ldap.c(612): [client IP:PORT2] AH01697: auth_ldap authenticate: accepting **USERNAME**, referer: http://domain
Tue Jul 04 14:28:44.559596 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid PID1:tid TID2] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client IP:PORT2] AH01626: authorization result of Require all denied: denied, referer: http://domain
Tue Jul 04 14:28:44.559596 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid PID1:tid TID2] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client IP:PORT2] AH01626: authorization result of Require valid-user : granted, referer: http://domain
Tue Jul 04 14:28:44.559596 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid PID1:tid TID2] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client IP:PORT2] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: http://domain
```

any ideas?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue.

Needed to gain access to WSGI environment variables, my application was running using falcon over apache - so accesses the correct variables via a middleware API class - falcon appends these variables to a 'env' dict within the Request class.

```
class AuthMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, req, resp):
         #auth validation here
```

http://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/quickstart.html